# Spring MVC Breadcrumb Framework

Tags: spring-mvc, breadcrumbs

What is the preferred method of maintaining breadcrumbs in a Spring MVC application?

Comment: MAybe you can use Spring Web Flow http://www.springsource.org/spring-web-flow

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about "preferred way" but I've used Sitemesh to do this. There is an example in [this Slideshare presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/guest9fefea/sitemesh) by an Atlassian developer (slide 30 onwards).

The trick is to specify the breadcrumb levels/elements in meta tags on the individual pages. The Sitemesh decorator then looks for these and incorporates them into the final layout.